# Python class instance return value

Tags: python, class, instance, return-value

My problem is as follows: I have a class Taskpane with a couple of methods. Instantiating works as it should. Now, when i show a list of all instantiated objects, i would like to print out a member variable per object for example the _tp_nr.

The following code returns the correct values, but it gets return in a strange(?) format.

This is the code:

```
#import weakref

class Taskpane():
    '''Taskpane class to hold all catalog taskpanes '''

    #'private' variables
    _tp_nr = ''
    _tp_title = ''
    _tp_component_name = ''

    #Static list for class instantiations
    _instances = []

    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, 
                  nr, 
                  title, 
                  component_name):

      self._tp_nr             = nr, 
      self._tp_title          = title, 
      self._tp_component_name = component_name

      #self.__class__._instances.append(weakref.proxy(self))
      self._instances.append(self)

    def __str__(self):
      return str( self._tp_nr )      

    def setTaskpaneId(self, value):
      self._tp_nr = value

    def getTaskpaneId(self):
      return str(self._tp_nr)

    def setTaskpaneTitle(self, value):
      self._tp_title = value

    def getTaskpaneTitle(self):
      return str(self._tp_title)

    def setTaskpaneComponentName(self, value):
      self._tp_component_name = value

    def getTaskpaneComponentName(self):
      return self._tp_component_name  

tp1 = Taskpane( '0', 'Title0', 'Component0' )
tp2 = Taskpane( '1', 'Title1', 'Component1' )

#print Taskpane._instances

#print tp1

for instance in Taskpane._instances:
    print( instance.getTaskpaneId() )

for instance in Taskpane._instances:
    print( instance.getTaskpaneTitle() )
```

Result:

```
('0',)
('1',)

('Title0',)
('Title1',)
```

The question is:
Why does it return the results in this kind of formatting? I would expect only to see:

```
'0'
'1'

('Title0')
('Title1')
```

When using:

```
for instance in Taskpane._instances:
    print( instance._tp_nr )
```

The result is the same.

Comment: You have just some syntax issues, so your answer won't help anybody else (hence my downvote).

Comment: @Alfe Except for the knowledge that this can be an issue...

Comment: Yeah, but that would in all cases be a random finding.  If the title was sth like "Why isn't this working with these trailing commas" all would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating tuples by using a comma:

```
self._tp_id             = nr,
```

The *comma* is what makes `_tp_id` a tuple:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove commas in the end of this strings in constructor:

```
self._tp_id             = nr, 
self._tp_title          = title,
```

Python treats such expressions as tuple with one element

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing commas, which are turning the value into a tuple.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Seems like a classic mistake.